# JQuery remove .append after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, timeout

Oh gosh here a lot today - oops

Folks, best way to do this:

```
$j('.done').append('Your services have been updated');
```

(that bits done)

but then remove the append  after say 5 seconds so that if a person resubmits a form(allowed) the append does not continue adding the text? i.e updated once "Your services have been updated", twice would read "Your services have been updated Your services have been updated" but I would only want Your services have been updated to show once

Answer (score 22):

```
(function (el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        el.children().remove('span');
    }, 5000);
}($j('.done').append('<span>Your services have been updated</span>')));
```

I know it looks weird.. I do it this way for self-containment. The append is immediately done when that anonymous function is called... that appended element is then saved as `el` in that anonymous scope, which itself is removed when the `timeout` fires after 5000ms.

**Edit:**

I edited the function above so it does not destroy the parent element (sorry about that)

Comment: very elegant IMO, not "weird"

Comment: Matt a dream, I agree with xyld  not "weird"

Comment: Thanks, hope it works for you. Please make sure you use my latest edit.. the previous snippets seemed to be killing the parent elements!

Comment: @Vincent Robert: A noteworthy point. Make sure to sufficiently differentiate the things you want to disappear by using a class if necessary.

Comment: @Matt what is j? A typo?

Answer (score 8):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-remove-append-after-5-seconds

set your time by incrementing or decrementing the `delay(#)`

```
$j('.done').delay(2000).fadeOut(200,function() {
    $(this).html('Your services have been updated').fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: Demo link is dead

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution :)
What code does:

1. creates a hidden <span> element
2. appends it to element with '.add-comment' class.
3. Fades in the new span,
4. after 4.5sec new span fades out and removes itself.

   ```
   jQuery('<span />',{ style:'display:none' })
       .html('Mesaj trimis...')
       .appendTo(jQuery('.add-comment'))
       .fadeIn('slow', 
           function(){
               var el = jQuery(this);
               setTimeout(function(){
                   el.fadeOut('slow',
                       function(){
                           jQuery(this).remove();
                       });
               }, 4500);
       });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I know its kinda late but I wanna share to you my solution as I added this to my global functionality .

```js
function alert(elem,content,type,posi){
    
    //elem - element to be inserted
    //content - content of the alert box (based from bootstrap)
    //type -  alert type
    //posi - either append or prepend    
    
    //primary, secondary, success, warning, info, danger, light, dark
    if(type == undefined)
       type = 'info';

    elem.find('.glb-alert').remove();
    var a = '<div class="alert alert-danger col-md-12 glb-alert" role="alert" >'+content+'</div>';
    
    if(posi == undefined|| posi == 'prepend')
       elem.prepend(a).find('.glb-alert').delay(1200).fadeOut();
    else if(posi == 'append')
       elem.append(a).find('.glb-alert').delay(1200).fadeOut();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the context here, but would it work to do, say

```
<span id="special_message">Your services have been updated.</span>`
```

and then remove that particular ID'd tag afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

```
// a little jQuery plugin...
(function($){ 
    $.fn.timeout = function(ms, callback)
    {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){ callback.call(self); }, ms);
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);

// ...and how to use it.
$("<span>Your services have been updated</span>")
    .appendTo('.done')
    .timeout(5000, function(){ this.remove(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might considering Ben Alman's doTimeout plugin - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

```
$j('<span>Your services have been updated</span>')
    .appendTo('.done')
    .doTimeout( 5000, 'remove' );
```

Comment: why use plugin if you can use .delay(5000)

Comment: delay() only works events that are placed in the effects queue.

Answer (score 0):

I like this method which uses a short fadeout before the span is removed. It also removes previous messages before appending.

```
$("<span class='js_msg'>Your services have been updated</span>")
    .appendTo($j('.done').children("span.js_msg").remove().end())
    .each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.fadeOut(500,function(){
                self.remove();
            });
        }, 4500); 
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('.card').append('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> This is a warning alert—check it out!</div>').delay(1000).queue(function(){
                $('.alert').remove()})
```

that's the way: you create an element by name which is div, then after 1 second the div is remove